# RecylerView item's maxWidth changes due to lots of elements

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

So I am building a chat application. I used `RecyclerView` to show the messages and set the `maxWidth` of the message list items to be 75% of the device width and in the layout, the width is `0dp` in `ConstraintLayout` so as to make it dynamic. This makes it concise for smaller texts and when it's a lot longer text, then it just sends it to the next line after reaching the maxWidth. Everything works perfectly fine until the list of items increases. When there is a lot of data, `RecyclerView` makes the width like the previous list item (I know `RecyclerView` recycles the views). One solution to this was to `setIsRecyclable(false);` in the `ViewHolder` of the `Adapter`. This did work but the list items overlap each other or when data of one list item changes, it overlaps itself creating another item on itself as the changed item. Since it is not recycling the views, it is creating new views on itself after any changes in the list item. I do not know what to do. Should I resort to `ListView` instead? Or is there any other solution? Here is my code for context's sake.

`ViewHolder` setting `maxWidth`

```java
public ChatViewHolder(@NonNull @NotNull View itemView, int width) {
    super(itemView);
    ...
    ...
   
    sendContainer.setMaxWidth(width);
    comeContainer.setMaxWidth(width);
}
```

`onCreateViewHolder` calculating the `maxWidth`

```java
    @Override
    public ChatViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull @NotNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.message_list_item, parent, false);
        int width = (int) (parent.getWidth() * 0.75);
        return new ChatViewHolder(view, width);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you actually need to do anything in the code itself. Constraint Layout is more than capable to achieve this by itself. Here is an example of a Chat Design I used once.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryBackground">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvMsgSelf"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:background="@drawable/drawable_chat_self"
        android:paddingStart="12dp"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:paddingEnd="12dp"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_max="wrap"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.72"
        tools:text="dgdgdgdgdfddg dfgdf gdf gdf gdf gdf gdfd g dg dfg dfg df gd gdf gdf g dfg dfg dfg dfg df g dfg df g dfgdfg" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTimeStampSelf"
        style="@style/StyleRegular"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorSecondaryText"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/tvMsgSelf"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvMsgSelf"
        tools:text="2 Jan,20, 10:50PM" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The main properties here are `app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.72"` and `app:layout_constraintWidth_max="wrap"`. This limits the width of this to 72% of any given screen from there on it wraps down.

Comment: I really get it. I said that it does work.  But `RecyclerView` recycles the views. So when there are lots of list items, the width sometimes becomes 75% for all instead of wrapping itself. Infact when you restart the app. It again shows everything perfectly.

Comment: It recycles and uses previous item's width, which was full 75% and uses that width makes even smaller text go 75% width

Comment: I don't know what to know\

Comment: I am saying you do not even need to bother with all that. Just design your layout in the way I mentioned above and it would automatically adjust to 75% of the screen. You do not need to make any changes in ViewHolder at all. You can adjust it all in the Constraint Layout itself @SimranSharma

Comment: I did that. But since it recycles the views, when you scroll fast width changes. When you restart then everything is back to perfect, just like I want but again after scrolling it's width changes

Comment: @SimranSharma I am unable to understand what you are implying. What do you mean the width changes?
The width will be at max 75%, but it can be shorter than that depending on the text

Comment: Yes @che10, you're right. I'll explain you. Suppose the text "hi". Now this is supposed to take pretty less space. But since it's previous list item has the text "hi i am ..................." and which is pretty long. So when you have lots of messages and you're scrolling, the `RecyclerView` just recycles and uses the previous message width i.e. 75% for the next message as well i.e. "hi". Which should not happen. But when you restart the app, the width of "hi" is again small like we want.

Comment: @SimranSharma
That should not be happening. Even if recyclerView recycles old view the data set to them will be new and thus the width will be readjusted.

Can you paste your layout code and complete adapter code for reference

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235530/discussion-between-simran-sharma-and-che10).

Comment: When you're scrolling fast and you have lots of data, that is the time it is happening